# Disconnect and Transfer voice calls programmatically in Amazon Connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

From my research, it appears there is no API call to disconnect or transfer phone calls in Amazon Connect.

The closest I could find are

- For disconnection, StopContact looks similar, but that appears only to work for Outbound Campaign calls.
- For transfers, there's a TransferContact API, but documentation says it only works for tasks, not calls.

It seems there would be a way to do this programmatically outside of contact flows?

Tried: Disconnecting a call via StopContact.
Result: Did not disconnect. After research, this API only works on Outbound Campaign calls, not regular inbound/outbound calls.

Tried: Disconnecting a call via TransferContact.
Result: Did not transfer. After research, this API only works on Tasks.

Comment: What's the use case for this?If this is outside a contact flow then the contact is with an agent. The Streams API allows you to customise the softphone and you can programtically control the call via that, so you could have a button in your custom softphone that auto transferred the call for example.

Comment: One example is an event in an external system causing a call to need to be transferred to a different queue or phone number. Most PBXs and contact center platforms have a "disconnect" and "transfer" API, no good reason NOT to have one on Amazon Connect IMO. To me it's more of a "why not" question than a "why". It should be part of the toolbelt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, before calls are routed to agents, they are in the control of a contact flow. There is no server-side API to enforce call control such as disconnect/transfer/mute/etc.

After calls are routed to agents, you could use the Amazon Connect Streams API to programmatically handle calls control (it's the API behind the CCP). Just be aware Streams is a client-side API, not server-side.

Comment: I thought as much, just wanted to confirm. Thank you!

Comment: There's no reason that within a contact flow you couldn't make decisions via lambda and then disconnect/transfer based on the results of the lambda. So for example if a call was queuing for an agent, have a loop prompts block in the flow with an interrupt every x seconds. Then have a lambda every and transfer/disconnect based on the results of the lambda. 

The biggest issue is that the loop prompts block is pretty horrid in that the prompts start from the beginning every time, so if you interrupt every 5 seconds you get the same 5 seconds of music over and over, which is less than ideal.